# WMSTileLayer event handler does not works in react leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, wms, react-leaflet-v3

According to react leaflet [documentation](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/) below code must work. Or am I doing any wrong? A suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
   <WMSTileLayer
          layers={ 'banbeis:division' }
          url={ `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/banbeis/wms` }
          maxZoom={ 18 }
          transparent={ true }
          format='image/png'
          opacity={ 0.5 }
          eventHandlers={ {
            click: () =>
                    {
                    console.log( 'layer clicked' ); <--------- does not work
                    },
                } }
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

WMS tilelayers don't handle `click` events, or any other mouse/touch/pointer events, as per https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-wms

Comment: IvanSanchez, Thank you for your response. I am new to the leaflet. could you please give me an idea of how to detect wms layer and call for feature info?

Comment: https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms